# Why was Finn advertised as the Force wielder in the trailers and posters?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-finn

In the trailers and posters, it was Finn who was about to fight Kylo Ren and it was Finn who was holding the Lightsaber. I was so confused when I saw Rey be the Force wielder.

I know they probably didn't want to spoil it, but it was also pretty misleading going into the movie.

So, why was Finn advertised as the Force wielder?

Comment: "I know they probably didn't want to spoil it" there's your reason right there.

Comment: Was the intention to mislead or to not spoil?

Comment: Are you saying that Finn _doesn't_ fight Kylo Ren with a lightsaber?  Did we watch the same movie?  And are you certain that Finn _isn't_ a Force user (albeit a less powerful one than Rey)?

Comment: No trailer I saw ever implied Finn was a Force user. Using a lightsaber does not a Force-user make. See General Grievous.

Comment: @CreationEdge Ah. That's true. I just assumed because we saw Kylo and Fin about to clash lightsabers so I just automatically assumed he was going to be a Jedi. I guess that's my own fault

Comment: “In the trailers and posters, it was Finn who was about to fight Kylo Ren and it was Finn who was holding the Lightsaber.” And in the movie, he fought Kylo Ren, with a lightsaber. But hey, if you write to J.J. he might give you your money back.

Comment: Because Disney's quarterly revenues were lower than they wanted.

Comment: This title is too spoilery. The posters and trailers don't really, only that he uses a lightsaber, which he does in the movie.

Answer (score 6):

I won't address whether Finn is a Force user or not, as your question is about the trailer. The simple answer is because trailers are designed to generate excitement and interest, often by showing interesting scenes out of context (and out of order).

They're saying  "Hey look! Doesn't this look neat? What's going on here? Watch the movie and get the whole story!"

The images you see in the trailer actually happen (Finn wields lightsaber, fights Kylo Ren) but lack the context (fights Kylo Ren poorly, gets curbstomped, Rey steps in).

Always remember, trailers often *lie* by implication.

Comment: To be fair, I wouldn't say anyone fought Ren _well_.  And I think he at least scored a glancing blow.  My impression was that previous wounds had more of an impact on that fight than anyone's level of proficiency with the Force or a lightsaber.

Comment: Why is this in a spoiler tag? There's nothing that would be a spoiler for someone clicking on a Force Awakens question

Answer (score 1):

Trailers are notorious for being edited in a way that generates excitement and enthusiasm for the film. That entails images and dialogue often being used out of context.

Viewers often draw conclusions from that. Maybe those conclusions were intended by the filmmakers, maybe not. However, they never explicitly said that Finn was the movie's "Force Wielder."

Comment: Trailers are notorious for utterly spoiling the enjoyment of so many films. The SW:TFA campaign was carefully crafted to mislead and NOT spoil the film.

Answer (score 0):

I think how the movie portrayed scenes with Finn it hints that he is a Force user, not as powerful as Rey is for some reason but I do think he is from connecting him to how he was clearly good at using the cannons in the Falcon and tie fighter like Luke except with an X-wing.

Also how Kylo noticed him after not firing the blaster.

A lot of people think that it was just that he didn't fire but I feel like Kylo could feel more than just that, especially since the scene with Snoke and Kylo about the "awakening" was before the introduction of Rey.

Rey will likely be the main focus, but I do think Finn will be more like a Jedi partner in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly evident, that the Force is within all of those who are highly active in both the Resistance and The First Order. Finn seems to actually move with the force, completing many objectives, although with tons of minor mistakes in between, along with overcoming insurmountable mountains and odds,sheer luck in non-Star-Wars terms. Finn fights Kylo Ren, and for true swordsman he had him at one point, after Ren pushed his crackling red lightsaber into Finn (by way of one of the two smaller sideways beams like the top of a " T ") Finn gets away and strikes Ren, who then turns his back on Finn in a moment of pain and weakness and a savage Finn could have killed him instantly then, by striking him when his back was turned, yet Finn uses the moment to regather strength and is actually being merciful here, because Finn has not killed a man in this manner, yet. For an untrained new resistance fighter, he did amazingly well against Kylo Ren and all that before the fight as well. Rey may use an unprecedented full use of the Force, but Finn arguably moves with it as well, enough to be a qualified resistance fighter and one of the few top dozen and half or so main characters of the entire Star Wars story.

Comment: But that doesn't really explain why the trailer implied that Finn was the *primary* heroic Force user, when that was actually Rey.